# C++ - matrix multipliction on one-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I've been writing a short programme with matrixes, as a part of a course teaching C++ - that's why I have to write multiplicion of matrixes in form of one-dimensional arrays.

That's the class:

```
class macierz{
    int *wsk;
    int size;
```

And that's the particular function that I have problem with:

```
macierz operator*(macierz &a)
            {
                macierz pm;
                if (size!=a.size)
                    return pm;
                else
                    {
                    pm.size = size;
                    pm.wsk = new int [pm.size*pm.size];
                    for (int i = 0; i<pm.size; i++)
                        for (int j = 0; j<pm.size; j++)
                            for (int h = 0; h<pm.size; h++)
                                pm.wsk[j+pm.size*i] = pm.wsk[j+pm.size*i] + wsk[h+pm.size*i] * a.wsk[h*pm.size+j];
                    return pm;
                    }
            }
```

It compiles, but when input is two 2x2 matrixes first and third element of the result are wrong (random 6digit number) so I think it's probably mistake in indexation which I can't pinn down.

In case it's something else and you would wish to compile it here are operators << and >>:

```
macierz()
    {

        wsk = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

~macierz()
    {
        if (wsk!=0)
            {delete []wsk;
            wsk = NULL;}
    }

friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &s, macierz &o1)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<(o1.size*o1.size); i++)
                s<<o1.wsk[i]<<endl;
                s<<endl;
            return s;
        }

friend istream & operator>>(istream &s, macierz &o1)
        {
            o1.~macierz();
            s>>o1.size;
            o1.wsk = new int[o1.size*o1.size];
            for (int i=0; i<(o1.size*o1.size); i++)
                    s>>o1.wsk[i];
            return s;
        }
```

Edit: As it has been a source of a bit of confusion - attribute size is the number of rows/columns in the matrix (programme is just for square matrixes). So mtarix with size=2 has an array of four elements.

Comment: Suggestion: Write a function to do the indexing math for you and always use that function. That way of you have an indexing bug, there is only one bug and it is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pm.wsk = new int [pm.size*pm.size];
```

This form of operator new doesn't initialize array elements. This one does:

```
pm.wsk = new int [pm.size*pm.size]();
```

Since you are updating elements of `pm.wsk` rather than using an accumulator variable in the inner loop, you do need elements of `pm.wsk` pre-initialized.

Comment: Thank you, I have completely missed that.